# Export SharePoint list to Excel - How remove column Item Type and Path

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel, export, path

When I export a SharePoint list to Excel using the built-in functionality, it also exports two columns called **Item Type** and **Path**.

Is there a way **OOTB** or programatically to exclude these columns from the export?

Comment: sir @charles  if you find solution for this, please write as an answer for us

Answer (score 1):

If the export is data that users will routinely access in Excel, you can hide the **Item Type** and **Path** columns in Excel, and then create a data connection between the workbook and the list.  Each time the workbook is opened the list data will be updated in Excel and the columns remain hidden.   [Click here](https://jennyssharepointtips.wordpress.com/2015/03/28/print-live-list-or-library-data-from-excel-workbooks-using-data-connections/) for step-by-step instructions for creating the data connection.  When I use this method, to make access easy for users, I add a link to the workbook on a web page in a site.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the **SharePoint** List API to do this, start here: [msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn531433(v=office.15).aspx)

Alternatively, you can try opening the list in DataSheet view and cut-and-paste the block of rows and columns that you are interested in.